# Execute action without redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a little question to community. Does ASP.NET MVC allow to execute an action of another controller without `RedirectToAction()` method and without creation of an instance of this controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible. For an instance method to execute there must be an instance to execute in. Action methods are simply methods like all other methods, so you always need an instance to call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you wish to have a View which returns nothing. No view. No nadda?

If so, u can return a [EmptyResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.emptyresult.aspx) *ViewResult* class...

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it through the `Reflection` technic, But It's **Not Recommended**. Shortly because it's not in the request/response/controller context.
Personally, I prefer to have an `internal static method(bla bla){...}` and call it where ever i want.
But if you drop the

> without creation of an instance of this controller

Clause, Then you can use [this methodology](http://www.productiverage.com/handing-off-to-another-aspnet-mvc-controller-action-without-redirecting). But as it explains, It's **Not Recommended Too**. the following is summarized:

```
var controller = new FooController();
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext, controller);
var jsonResult = controller.BlaMethod(someInputParams);
```